# Column break interfering with continuous section break and text spacing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

[why can't my text on the right (in 3 columns) move above the column break on the left????](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C57nt.png)

Image explains it all. Driving me bonkers.

Comment: No, the image doesn't explain it all.  If you're a Word user, you should be able to use words; please describe your situation and explain what you want.     :-)     Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

In Word you set a number of columns for a section. The next section doesn't start in the last column of the previous section but starts from its own first column on the left. Sections cannot be nested.

If you would like to have multiple columns inside your second column in the first section then I think you could remove section break and use tabs to simulate columns.